# FluentValidation LogOnFailure override

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, fluentvalidation

Inside my validator class I have couple of rules.
I need to log to database some validation errors.

Here are my validators:

```
RuleFor(u => u.LastName)
    .Cascade(CascadeMode.StopOnFirstFailure)
    .NotEmpty().WithMessage("Last name is required")
    .Length(3, 20).WithMessage("Must have between 3 and 20 letters");

RuleFor(u => u.BirthDate)
    .Cascade(CascadeMode.StopOnFirstFailure)
    .NotNull().WithMessage("Birth date is required")
    .Must(c => c > new DateTime(1920, 01, 01)).WithMessage("Too old");

RuleFor(u => u.Age)
    .Cascade(CascadeMode.StopOnFirstFailure)
    .NotNull().WithMessage("This is required")
    .GreaterThan(18).WithMessage("Must be at least 18")
    .Must((model, age, context) =>
    {
        DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
        int ageToCompare = today.Year - model.BirthDate.Year;
        return ageToCompare == age;
    }).WithMessage("Invalid age");
```

For above rules I'd like to log only specific error messages.
I'm aware that I can use OnAnyFailure like this:

```
RuleFor(u => u.Age)
    .Cascade(CascadeMode.StopOnFirstFailure)
    .NotNull().WithMessage("This is required")
    .GreaterThan(18).WithMessage("Must be at least 18").OnAnyFailure(LogOnFailure)
    .Must((model, age, context) =>
    {
        DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
        int ageToCompare = today.Year - model.BirthDate.Year;
        return ageToCompare == age;
    }).WithMessage("Invalid age").OnAnyFailure(LogOnFailure)

private void LogOnFailure(CreateAccountBindingModel obj))
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(obj);
    }
```

but this way I won't be able to log anything useful, because `OnAnyFailure` takes BindingModel as parameter, so I'll only get values user entered without error messages.

I've tried to create extension method that would work as `OnAnyFailure` but because I'm new to FluentValidation I wasn't able to even compile my code.

Below is my code:

```
public static class IRuleBuilderOptionsExtensions
{
    public static IRuleBuilderOptions<T, TProperty> OnAnyFailure<T, TProperty>(this IRuleBuilderOptions<T, TProperty> rule, Action<T, PropertyValidatorContext> onFailure)
    {
        return rule;
        //return rule.Configure(config => {
        //  config.OnFailure = onFailure.CoerceToNonGeneric();
        //});
    }
}
```

This way I could be able to call:

```
private void LogOnFailure(CreateAccountBindingModel obj), PropertyValidatorContext context)
{
    //log logic
}
```

Basically what I need is to create override for `LogOnFailure` that will be able to access PropertyValidatorContext.

Comment: Creating override will not help, because the framework will call `PropertyRule.OnFailure` with single parameter (instance to validate).

Comment: @AlekseyL. So is there another way? Name of method can be different, it don't have to be override. I'd like to get my model and PropertyValidationContext when error occurs, just like `OnAnyFailure`

Comment: I'm not aware of such extensibility point, but you can do this in `ActionFilter` - check model state and log all errors. Let me know if you need example for this.

Comment: @AlekseyL.  I've posted my current solution code in FluentValidation repo (github.com/JeremySkinner/FluentValidation/issues/…) and I'm waiting for Jeremy review. I've implemented this solution in my project and it works fine, but I'd like to get author review on that before I post it here. Maybe You could look at it and share Your thoughts?

Comment: Why not just log error inside specific `Must` validators?

Comment: @AlekseyL. I thought about that, but sometimes I want to log errors using build-in validators (`NotNull`, `GreaterThan`) also this way I can have single Log function and I can call it anywhere I want using `OnFailure` method. Here is correct link: https://github.com/JeremySkinner/FluentValidation/issues/299

Answer (score 2):

You can validate your model second time to display it:

```
public class MyValidator
{
    public MyValidator()
    {
        // default behavior
        Validate();

        // works only when RuleSet specified explicitly as "Debug"
        RuleSet("Debug", ()=> {
            Validate();
            FailAndLogErrors();
        })

        private void Validate()
        {
            RuleFor(u => u.Age)
                //... set cascade mode, define rules with error messages
            RuleFor(u => u.LastName)
                //... set cascade mode, define rules with error messages
            RuleFor(u => u.BirthDate)
                //... set cascade mode, define rules with error messages
        }

        // force failing
        private void FailAndLogErrors()
        {
            RuleFor(m => m)
                .Must(m => false)
                .WithName("_fakeProperty_")
                .OnAnyFailure(m => LogIfFailed(this, m))
        }

        private void LogIfFailed(MyValidator validator, CreateAccountBindingModel obj))
        {
            var errors = validator.Validate(obj, "Debug").Errors;
            if (errors.Count > 1) // prevent displaying valid model
            {
                var fakeError = errors.First(e => e.PropertyName == "_fakeProperty_");
                errors.Remove(fakeError);
                WriteErrors(errors);
            }
        }

        private void WriteErrors(IList<ValidationFailure> errors)
        {
            foreach(var e in errors)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(e);
            }
            Debug.WriteLine("");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks,
 private void LogIfFailed(MyValidator validator, CreateAccountBindingModel obj)

should only have one right bracket in the end