# FluentValidation modify error message in Must function

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, fluentvalidation

Inside class that is responsible for validation I have simple rule:

```
RuleFor(u => u.Id)
    .Cascade(CascadeMode.StopOnFirstFailure)
    .NotEmpty().WithMessage("Id is required")
    .Must(ValidateId);
```

and below is my `ValidateId` function:

```
private bool ValidateId(CreateAccountBindingModel model, string id, PropertyValidatorContext context)
{
    if (id=="test")
    {
        context.Rule.CurrentValidator.ErrorCodeSource = new StaticStringSource("You are testing");
        return false;
    }

    var idValid = IdValidator.IsValid(id);
    if (!idValid)
    {
        context.Rule.CurrentValidator.ErrorCodeSource = new StaticStringSource("Id is invalid");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

If I run my validator I get default error, not my custom errors I'm specifying inside my function.
I've tried setting them using:

```
context.Rule.CurrentValidator.ErrorCodeSource = new StaticStringSource("Id is invalid");
```

but without any luck.

How can I define error message inside validation function?

Comment: @AlekseyL.sorry for such late reply. I've created extension that allows me to call `OnFailure` for each rule. I've posted my code in FluentValidation repo (https://github.com/JeremySkinner/FluentValidation/issues/299#issuecomment-233904267) and I'm waiting for Jeremy review. I've implemented this solution in my project and it works fine, but I'd like to get author review  on that before I post it here. Maybe You could look at it?

Comment: I think this is not related to this question..

Comment: @AlekseyL. Sorry about that. I've mistaken questions. That link is related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38436630/fluentvalidation-logonfailure-override

Comment: You should change the accepted answer. See my comment under it. Keeping it there steers people in the wrong direction. I'm sure the person who answered in good faith would agree, having read the reference in my comment.

Comment: @onefootswill I've just changed the accepted answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use CustomValidator instead:

```
RuleFor(u => u.Id)
    .Cascade(CascadeMode.StopOnFirstFailure)
    .NotEmpty().WithMessage("Id is required")
    .Custom(ValidateId);
```

And below - `ValidateId` method:

```
private void ValidateId(string id, CustomContext context)
{
    if (id == "test")
    {
         context.AddFailure("You are testing");
    }
    var idValid = IdValidator.IsValid(id);
    if (!idValid)
    {
        context.AddFailure("Id is invalid");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't implement what you are trying to do with a custom validation function as you can do it using `FluentValidation` itself:

```
RuleFor(u => u.Id)
 .Cascade(CascadeMode.StopOnFirstFailure)
 .Must(x => x !="test").WithMessage("You are testing.")
 .Must(x => IdValidator.IsValid(x)).WithMessage("Id is invalid.");
```

Comment: I'll try that, but inside my custom validation function I have more logic, including logging and database access, bo I'd be great if I could set that error message from my custom function.